# Geometry with TranslateTransform sometimes loses fill

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a framework for drawing made in C#. Recently I've been trying to do something and noticed the following problem:

When I draw a `Geometry` manually on `DrawingVisual` using its `RenderOpen`, and then move it using `TranslateTransform`, I sometime lose the fill.

To see what happens, you can insert the following framework element to a Window and run it:

```
class MyVisual : FrameworkElement {
        private readonly DrawingVisual _visual = new DrawingVisual();
        private readonly Geometry _geom;
        private readonly Random _r = new Random();

        public MyVisual()
        {
            AddVisualChild(_visual);

            _geom = Geometry.Parse("M 95 100 L 130 130 95 160 Z").Clone();
            _geom.Transform = new TranslateTransform();

            UpdateVisual();
        }

        public void MoveGeom() {
            var transform = _geom.Transform as TranslateTransform;

            var x = _r.Next(-60, 200);
            var y = _r.Next(-60, 200);
            transform.X = x;
            transform.Y = y;
        }

        void UpdateVisual()
        {
            using (var dc = _visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                UpdateVisual(dc);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateVisual(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            var color = Brushes.Red;
            var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);

            dc.DrawGeometry(color, pen, _geom);
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount => 1;
        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => _visual;
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Timer _t = new Timer(500) { AutoReset = true };
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _t.Elapsed += (x, y) => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _vis.MoveGeom());

            _t.Start();
        }
    }
```

Is this a known issue, is there some simple workaround for it, or some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems to solve this issue:

```
public void MoveGeom()
{
    var x = _r.Next(-60, 200);
    var y = _r.Next(-60, 200);

    _geom.Transform = new TranslateTransform(x, y);
}
```

Obviously there is a problem when the two coordinates are set separately because setting the single coordinates causes two updates and the rendering process is confused by that in any way.

Comment: Thanks for a quick workaround. Don't see why two updates would cause rendering process to confuse, but hope this will save someone some trouble.